# Finding a value inside a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a boolean result if a specific value is inside the following list. Unfortunately i am dealing with some error which i dont know how to fix it

```
list = [array(['63977', '63981', '91916', '63908', '97158', '63906', '63910',
        '63956', '63970', '63969', 'Other'], dtype='<U5')]
```

For example i was trying to find value 63977 and my try was :

```
if '63977' in list:
    print('find it')
```

but i got the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Why don't you just use: 

if list .any()=='63977':
  print('found it')
else:
  print('not found')

For this reason, you might take a look into this: 
https://researchdatapod.com/python-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous-use-a-any-or-a-all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created nested list so that code is not doing what you think it is.
You are actually checking if specific element is in outer array but instead you should search if element exists in inner array.

Try next:

```
from numpy import array

my_list = [array(['63977', '63981', '91916', '63908', '97158', '63906', '63910',
        '63956', '63970', '63969', 'Other'], dtype='<U5')]

if '63977' in my_list[0]:
    print('find it')
```

If you create list like this:

```
my_list = array(['63977', '63981', '91916', '63908', '97158', '63906', '63910',
        '63956', '63970', '63969', 'Other'], dtype='<U5')
```

Then your code would work:

```
if '63977' in my_list:
    print('find it')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You shouldn't call your own variable `list` because you overwrite the built-in function [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). In fact, you shouldn't give any variable the same name as a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). It's confusing and leads to errors.